# Xamarin.Forms on VSCode

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

Is there any way to develop and run a Xamarin.forms application in VS CODE instead of Visual studio 2022?

Has anyone tried and succeeded?

Comment: I use Rider (only) for Xamarin.Forms development. To archive using only VS Code, you would most probably need Android Studio (it uses the same JetBrains platform as Rider, also, it's the easiest way), or manually install Android SKD, NDK, and an appropriate version of Java. Then you would need a Qemu virtualization tool or similar for running Android to have an app running inside, or connected device via ADB.
But, that would be only the beginning and easy part. You would probably need to define your own debug session in VS Code (connect to adb, install app, connect debugger and run app).

Comment: VS Code doesn't support the xamarin.forms development. Because you need to run the code on the windows, ios or the android platform. And for the two mobile phone platform, you need to connect to the simulator or a physical device to run it. The VS Code does' t have a such function.

Answer (score 5):

There's several things Visual Studio does as an IDE for your Xamarin applications-

1. develop (edit code)
2. build (compile)
3. deploy (install),
4. debug (while
   running)

Using VSCode and Xamarin code,

1. Yes, you can obviously develop on VSCode since it's like any other text editor, which works well for most of Xamarin Forms (except the iOS LaunchScreen that uses a Storyboard file)
2. Yes, You can also build using VSCode's inbuilt terminal using commands like this `msbuild Sample.iOS/Sample.iOS.csproj /verbosity:normal /t:Rebuild /p:Platform=iPhoneSimulator /p:Configuration=Debug`
3. Yes, after building, you can deploy to a simulator using commands like this `xcrun simctl install booted Sample.iOS.app`
4. No, you can't debug while running the app or place breakpoints.

I have written about [deploying Xamarin apps from VS Code in detail](https://blog.devgenius.io/build-xamarin-apps-with-vs-code-to-m1-macs-iphones-android-11bc158f3773?sk=bc296c444465642b9d5771aef3f5e731). Surprisingly, you can also [deploy Xamarin apps directly to the Apple AppStore](https://prototypemakers.medium.com/maui-xamarin-ios-app-store-publishing-with-one-command-dea7adbfea8e?sk=57f39592cdc1717bb2edab6ecc64a9d6) and it takes less than a minute. With MAUI, thanks to [Uno's VS code plugin](https://platform.uno/blog/announcing-net-mobile-debugging-in-vs-code-mobile-development-in-vs-code-with-uno-platform-or-net-maui/), you can also debug while running